# Add item to the header-bar in a cockpit based app

Tags: cumulocity

I want to know if is possible to add an item in the header-bar element in a cockpit based app.

[image]

I have search a lot [here](http://resources.cumulocity.com/documentation/jssdk/latest/#/api) but without luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At least not directly with the SDK. You can add items to the menu located behind the plus icon in the bar.